# Spring JSon try to initialise attribute with FetchType Lazy

Tags: json, spring, lazy-initialization

I'm trying to make work a rest controller. But when i try a GET method, Json try to build the json by getting access to the Lazy association.And i don't want it. If if st FetchType.EAGER, it recursively load all the associations wich i don't want too.
The behavior i want is just load attributes without fetching Lazy association

Comment: Please show us the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@JsonIgnore` to the attribute that you don't wanna fetch or include in the Json conversion.

Example :

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany
private List<SomeAttribute> attributes;
```

But it is not recommended to use your Entities direclty.You should use some `DTO` representations that contain only the data that you need to transfer.

Comment: Yep in fact i found that using DTO representations is the best way to do it . Thanks

Comment: @Queezzy , you welcome can you mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly return your jpa entities in your rest response.

But if you really want to go that way, some json serialisation framework have option to deal with uninitialiezd jpa proxy *eg : jackson-datatype-hibernate3*